# Is it possible to access the DDP connection inside a function called by a method?

Tags: meteor

```
Meteor.methods
  foo: ->
    // this.connection is the DDP connection
    SomePackage.bar()
```

I'd like to be able to access the `connection` inside my package's `bar` function without making the caller (a user of my package) pass the connection as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: `DDP._CurrentInvocation.get().connection`

Related: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6369